# Scala: How to make a protected method accessible to sub-classes (on other instances)?

Tags: scala, inheritance, access-modifiers

I'm trying to do something like this:

```scala
trait A[Out] {
    protected def foo(): Out
}

trait B extends A[Int]

class WrapperB(b: B) extends B {
    override protected def foo(): Int = b.foo() + 1
}
```

This won't compile, as `WrapperB` has no access to `b.foo()`.

There are a few ways to resolve this, but these won't work for me:

1. Make `foo` public: won't work, because I want it to stay `protected`.
2. Use a package scope: won't work, because I intend to have many `B`s in different packages.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
trait A[Out] {
  protected def foo(): Out
}

trait B extends A[Int] {
  protected def gimme(that: B) = that.foo()
}

class WrapperB(b: B) extends B {
  override protected def foo(): Int = gimme(b) + 1
}
```

I have never liked the idea that `private` and `protected` can access other value's methods, I think it's bad design. `private` should mean `private[this]`. If you need cross-value access, I think you should declare `private[my-package]`, even if it means choosing a common base package in your case.

Comment: I mostly agree, and that's usually a matter of "composition over inheritance". Regardless, in my current situation (as in many others) I'm bound to the limitations of a code written a long time ago in a galaxy far far away...